# Kivy: How to use toggle button to lock scaling and translation of an image in scatter layout?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, togglebutton

This has probably a very simple solution but I'm new to Kivy and I can't figure it out:

I use scatter layout to hold image in the application so I can scale and move it, however I woild like to implement an option to lock scaling and transformation with toggle button so it would be available again when I "unpress" the button.

No errors are returned however the scaling still works.

I'm working on this combining python and KV file.

py code:

```
class ScreenStartMapping(Screen):
image_path = StringProperty('')
do_scale = BooleanProperty()      
def mapLine(self, *args):    
    if args[1] == "down":
        print args[1]
        self.do_scale = False
        print self.do_scale
    elif args[1] == "normal":
        print args[1]
        self.do_scale = True
        print self.do_scale
```

and Kivy file defining entire screen:

```
<ScreenStartMapping>:
    GridLayout:
        id: gl
        rows: 2
        ScatterLayout:
            id: sl
            do_rotation: False
            do_scale: toggleMappingMode
            auto_bring_to_front: False
            Image:
                source: root.image_path
                canvas:
                    Line: 

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: .1,.1,.1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: (root.size[0], root.size[1]/10)

            Button:
                background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
                pos: self.pos
                size: (root.size[0]/5, root.size[1]/10)
                text: "Back"
                font_name: "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\segoescb.ttf"
                on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"

            ToggleButton:
                id: toggleMappingMode
                background_color: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5)
                pos: (root.size[0]/5, self.pos[1])
                size: (root.size[0]/5, root.size[1]/10)
                text: "Draw line"
                font_name: "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\segoescb.ttf"
                on_state:
                    root.mapLine(*args)
```

Thank you very much for your help would also appreciate any suggestions how to make this better .

Comment: Please post some example code demonstrating what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So problem solved. As I thougt it was very basic beginner problem with me not knowing how exacly access the property in second widget from first.